# Perl function to find the longest word from each separate array

Tags: arrays, perl, function, cpu-word

I have a task:

**There are several arrays, each element of which is a word. Create a function which finds the longest word from each given array and returns the result as a list. References to arrays should be passed as arguments to the function.**

This function gives me the longest word from two arrays. I just didn't get it how to make it find the longest words from each separate array.

```
use strict;
my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five seven/;
my $arr1 = \@arr1;
my $arr2 = \@arr2;
my @sorted_words;

sub func {
  for (@_) {
    for (@$_){
     @sorted_words = sort {length($b) <=> length ($a)} $_;}
  }
  print "The longest word is: $sorted_words[0]\n";
}
func($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: Is there a particular line that you don't understand, or do you want us to explain Perl syntax from the beginning?
(OT: [It's "Perl", not "PERL".](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq1.html#Whats-the-difference-between-perl-and-Perl-))

Comment: When looking for the largest, longest, whatever-est value in an array, a simple traversal with `foreach` is more efficient than a `sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is already in the "Nested loops" section of the first lecture of any first introduction to algorithms course...

The basic algorithm for finding the "best" value in an array according to some parameter is:

```
best ← worst possible value
for each value in array
    if value is better than best
        then best ← value
    end if
end for each
```

What you want is the longest string, so the worst case is an empty string. In Perl, that would give you:

```
my @array = qw/one two three/;
my $best = '';
for my $value (@array) {
    if (length $value > length $best) {
        $best = $value;
    }
}
```

If you want to do this for many arrays, just add an additional outer loop:

```
best_array ← ()
for each array in array_of_array
    best ← worst possible value
    for each value in array
        if value is better than best
            then best ← value
        end if
    end for each
    best_array ← best_array, best
end for each
```

Or, in Perl:

```
my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five seven/;
my @arr3 = qw/six eight nine/;
my @array_of_arrays = (\@arr1, \@arr2, \@arr3);
my @longest_words;

for my $array (@array_of_arrays) {
    my $best = '';
    for my $value (@$array) {   # notice "@$" to dereference the array
        if (length $value > length $best) {
            $best = $value;
        }
    }
    push @longest_words, $best;
}
```

**Update: subroutine**

I have just realised the question specifically asked for a subroutine. The code above is easy to change into a subroutine:

```
my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five seven/;
my @arr3 = qw/six eight nine/;
my @array_of_arrays = (\@arr1, \@arr2, \@arr3);

sub funct {
    my @longest_words;
    for my $array (@_) {
        my $best = '';
        for my $value (@$array) {   # notice "@$" to dereference the array
            if (length $value > length $best) {
                $best = $value;
            }
        }
        push @longest_words, $best;
    }
    return @longest_words;
}

my @longest_words = funct(@array_of_arrays);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks you for a function which *"returns the result as a list"*, so printing the answers inside the function isn't the answer.

You need to process the arrays one by one and keep track of all the longest words you have found so far, then return them all at the end.

Something like this works fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five seven/;

sub func {
  my @max;
  for my $list (@_) {
    my @sorted = sort { length($b) <=> length ($a) } @$list;
    push @max, $sorted[0];
  }
  @max;
}

my @longest = func(\@arr1, \@arr2);
printf "The longest words are: %s\n", join ', ', @longest;
```

#### Output

```
The longest words are: three, seven
```

But I would write a subroutine that returned the longest word out of *one* array and then make use of [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to create a list of all the longest words.

That would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five seven/;

sub longest {
  my ($list) = @_;
  my $longest = '';
  for (@$list) {
    $longest = $_ if length > length($longest);
  }
  $longest;
}

sub func {
  map longest($_), @_;
}

my @longest = func(\@arr1, \@arr2);
printf "The longest words are: %s\n", join ', ', @longest;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to enable the function to be called with either an array or an array of arrays.  If called with the latter, just recursively call the function to get the values.

The following does that and uses [`List::Util reduce`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) to determine the max [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @AoA = (
    [qw(one two three)],
    [qw(four five seven)],
    [qw(six eight nine)],
);

sub longest {
    return map {longest(@$_)} @_ if ref $_[0];
    return reduce {length $b > length $a ? $b : $a} @_;
}

my @longest_words = longest(@AoA);
print "@longest_words\n";
```

Outputs:

```
three seven eight
```

Comment: +1 for `reduce`, but IMHO using two subroutines rather than one with recursion would be more readable and also a bit faster.

Comment: TY.  If I didn't find the requirement to process AoA's contrived to begin with, I'd agree.  As it was, I just thought this a useful technique to demonstrate, along with the use of `reduce`.

Answer (score -2):

If you call the subroutine with each array separately, it will work the way you want it.

Use

```
func($arr1);
func($arr2);
```

instead of:

```
func($arr1, $arr2);
```

BTW, you should now that the subroutine works properly only for one array. Try changing your array names by renaming @arr1 to @arr2 and @arr2 to @arr1 and run your original program.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why I am being downvoted? I really do not understand.

Comment: The question was to *"Create a function which finds the longest word from each given array and returns the result as a list"*. You don't specify your subroutine `func` but you don't save its return value, and calling it twice doesn't make it return a list